# I'm getting this message on Parity

Tags: parity, network

I'm getting this message on Parity

> "Connecting to the Parity Node. If this informational message
>   persists, please ensure that your Parity node is running and reachable
>   on the network."

I guess I pressed the wrong button, learning how to use it.

How to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Please add some more information. My guess is that you get this message in your browser when trying to connect to the browser UI interface. My questions are: What is the URL that you entered? What is the command used to start the node? If a .toml config file was specified, please paste the contents.

Comment: Restarting the browser and parity did not help. I also had to reboot the machine. I suspect there was a conflict with the metamask plugin but disabling it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Your Parity node is down.

Just (re)start it and this message will go away.

*Disclosure, I work for Parity.*

Comment: But what are reasons node would go down?  Is there a log file to check why?  Same happened to me, because my C drive filled up.

Comment: Please ping me on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/paritytech/parity) and we can check the logs together.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because Parity installed on my C Drive, and downloading the blockchain filled up the disk.  This probably was causing the Parity node program to crash.  I will try to migrate it or re-install on the other disk drive that has much more space.

Comment: This was exactly my case.

Answer (score 0):

Is parity on the same machine that you're connecting from or is the browser/client/etc. on another machine on the network?  If the machines are different then you might have a firewall issue.  In either case, you might try looking for some curl commands to send to port 8545 to make sure that it's working and reachable at that port.  Also see if you have another application  that is preventing Parity from broadcasting on the UI port (8180 I think?)